# Why can't I view my token on https://rinkeby.etherscan.io/token-search?

Tags: contract-development, tokens, etherscan, rinkeby

I have created a token contract on the Rinkeby Testnet:
https://rinkeby.etherscan.io/address/0x89b901df4f818bb848a6fb64892253fc01f7f559

The contract address is viewable on Etherscan, but when I search https://rinkeby.etherscan.io/token-search for the token, I get the result:
"Sorry! We were unable to locate any valid Token Transfer Events for Contract..."

I have successfully transferred tokens between wallets and the token shows up on https://www.myetherwallet.com/#contracts.

Why am I not able to view the token on Etherscan?

Comment: Can you share the source code for your token? I have two theories: 1) From the error message, it sounds like perhaps Etherscan finds tokens via the events they log, and maybe you're not logging the expected event. 2) Perhaps Etherscan requires verified source code for tokens.

Comment: (I think theory #1 is much more likely.)

Comment: I pretty much exactly copied the Minimum viable token from here https://www.ethereum.org/token. Does the code for this token not include the required info for it to be logged by etherscan? Regarding my actual source code, i lost it. I didn't realize that the code wouldn't be saved anywhere once I deploy it.

Comment: It's true that the "Minimum viable token" code does not include the Transfer event, which I think is what etherscan.io looks for. It's also missing a bunch of other ERC20 token functions. So in short, you don't have an ERC20 token, and that's why Etherscan doesn't recognize your token as an ERC20 token. :-)

Comment: Ok, I thought the error may be something like that. Thanks for your help! First positive response I've had on stack exchange.